# Vector space vs vectorspace

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I've been using an algebra book called "abstract algebra" by Paul Garrett, and I noticed he makes the interesting choice of writing vectorspace instead of vector space. For example, he writes "The space of k-linear maps from one k-vectorspace to another is a k-vectorspace..."

Now he does not present any reasons for this choice, forcing me to come up with my own. One reason can be  related to redaction (e.g. saving up space given that it is quite a big book), but that's not convincing enough to me.

Another possible reason is that the author could have been influenced by the German tendency to concatenate words together to make up new ones. And here I have to wonder whether this is common among English writers, given that I am not a native speaker.

Comment: If you're going to be using the term constantly, and attaching prefixes to it, then treating it as a single unspaced word is a good idea. Otherwise you'd be fussing with hyphens, minus signs, M- and N-dashes and gods know what-all. Math has enough typographic problems without importing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage makes great sense as opposed to k-vector-space as hyphens do not add to clarity. The concatenation is likely more to do with meaning than with saving type space. If the author is German then there may be some cause from German compound word affinity but not likely. I think this has more to do with meaning as in the use of space-time or spacetime when working with relativistic physics. Identifying it with k versus some other letter, it makes sense that the space is defined only by the vectors of choice and called a vectorspace.

I have only found one place, below, which makes unapologetic and unexplained use of the term vectorspace. All other searches have "helped out" by breaking up the term.

https://medium.com/codex/shape-of-thought-enhancing-neural-networks-with-vectorspaces-7b0ebb8f5375